# Python confusion

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I am getting -- " unindent does not match any outer indentation level" while coding in browser online for repl. It's showing error in `prices = {}` Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Query the price once every N seconds.
    for _ in iter(range(N)):
        quotes = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(QUERY.format(random.random())).read())
        prices = {}
        for quote in quotes:
            stock, bid_price, ask_price, price = getDataPoint(quote)
      prices[stock] = price
            print ("Quoted %s at (bid:%s, ask:%s, price:%s)" % (stock, bid_price, ask_price, price))

        print ("Ratio %s" % getRatio(prices['ABC', prices['DEF']))
```

Comment: Indentation *means something* in Python.  You can't position your code horizontally however you want, you have to use it to indicate the structure of your program - it's the only want to indicate where the end of a loop or function is, for example.

Comment: You have tabs for the first two lines that are indented, and then just spaces for the `prices = {}` line. You must make your indents uniform.

Comment: @tdelaney Block, not block scope. Python doesn't have block scopes.

Comment: @chepner - its "suite" really, but that's a bit obscure. I'll delete the comment anyway.

Comment: yea. thanks ! It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at line 7

```
prices[stock] = price
```

This particular line. As this line is not indented with the second loop. Since python makes use of procedural language, if you miss out on adding tabs or spaces between your lines of code, then you will most likely experience this error. ... While programming you haven't indented the `prices[stock] = price`  line.

Updated Code-

```
# Query the price once every N seconds.
for _ in iter(range(N)):
    quotes = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(QUERY.format(random.random())).read())
    prices = {}
    for quote in quotes:
        stock, bid_price, ask_price, price = getDataPoint(quote)
        prices[stock] = price
        print ("Quoted %s at (bid:%s, ask:%s, price:%s)" % (stock, bid_price, ask_price, price))

    print ("Ratio %s" % getRatio(prices['ABC', prices['DEF']))
```

In case you don't want to change the value of `prices[stock]` inside the second loop, just paste that after the `print ("Quoted %s at (bid:%s, ask:%s, price:%s)" % (stock, bid_price, ask_price, price))` line and indent it according to the first loop.

I hope this helped...